# How to build a InfoPath form on the site

Tags: development, infopath

I listened that it could be done that InfoPath Form is on the Site with WebPart. How Could be it Done? It should be a InfoPath form when I could on a site put date start of range, and date end of a range. How to correlate InfoPath with a WebPart on a site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll need to do is create yourself an InfoPath form, and publish it to your site, team site, etc. Once you complete that, you can add what's called an "InfoPath Web Part" onto your site - it's listed under "Forms" in the web part manager, titled "InfoPath Form Web Part".

There are two sites, one from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office2010developertrainingcourse_infopathlab_topic3#_Toc289157748), and one on [C# Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/infopath-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010/) that explain this in detail.

Comment: And Could I put a Infopath Template to the existing WebPart made in Visual Studio ?

Comment: You can use any infopath form published to SharePoint, in the web part. Yes, You just need to set the property of the web part to point to the infopath form.

Comment: But how do it. Have You got any samples?

Comment: Please follow the steps provided on the sites, they both go into very much detail - especially, the MSDN one.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you publish Infopath form template to a sharepoint site, it is being available and used as a web part.

As a matter of fact, I do not grasp how it is possible to use Infopath form at a sharepoint site without Infopath Web Part engagement at all!

Infopath Form template is created in and published from Infopath Designer, from client machine to sharepoint server. The Infopath Designer is installed as part of Microsoft Office suite on client machine (which can be also the same machine as server).